# Issues with the C Standard Library?

Tags: c, stdio, standard-library, std

I've read from various sources about there being a lot of bugs, issues and design flaws in the C Standard library. Some to do with string handling functions, some with I/O etc.

Is this true? If so, can anyone list some of the most common known issues?

Note: I'm talking about the **ISO C Library**.

Comment: There is no buggy code; there are only buggy people who write code.

Comment: one issue is, as i recall, the const incorrectness of some of the string functions, taking a const string and returning pointer to non-const. check it.

Comment: Which sources are these?  And are they talking about the *design* of the standard library, or a particular *implementation* of the standard library?

Comment: C doesn't have Strings.  It's likely that if someone is complaining about string handling in C, they don't have a proper understanding of C.  Can't speak to the I/O side, but if it's on the same site, probably the same.

Comment: The biggest problems are about thread safety however, this are not bugs. as delnan stated...

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan the sea doesn't have water. seriously, are you out of your mind?

Comment: @KerrekSB So I take it `int average(int *xs, size_t num) { int acc, i; for (i = 0; i <= num; i = i++) acc += xs[i]; }` is bug-free and I have a cockroach in my pants?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Those aren't really bugs, though, but rather delibarate choices to make const-casts part of the interface in a language that doesn't have function overloading.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf No, I'm right.  C doesn't have strings.  The String library is a series of methods that operate on Char* s.  Sorry you didn't get to see the edited version of that comment, but a lot of people aren't careful enough with their pointers, and memory management, then get upset about C "doing it wrong."

Comment: @Frankie: (1) nobody except you have talked about a library named "String". (2) you're comment about C lacking strings is utter nonsense, to the degree that i had to question your sanity. (3) you have provided an answer to my question.

Comment: @TheCloseVoters Seriously, how is this _Not Constructive_ ? Knowing about some of the issues in the standard library is pretty constructive for me. It helps me avoid mistakes and pitfalls, write better code and predict runtime behaviour. If that's not _contructive_ enough, then what is?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: Nobody is saying that this is a bad question; it's just not a question that lends itself well to SO's question-answer format. It's much more of an invitation to an open-ended treatise or discussion. Interesting for sure, but maybe not the right place.

Comment: @Alf - Frankie is right in the sense that C doesn't have a string *data type* the way languages like C++ or Java (or even old-skool BASIC, Pascal, and Fortran 77) do.  However, C string library functions do operate on string *data* (sequences of character values terminated by a 0).  And yes, if you don't understand the distinction, you're probably going to think the string library functions are badly designed, when in truth they're working from a different paradigm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here are a couple of the known *design* issues:

1. Input functions like `gets` (deprecated in C99, gone in C11, but still lurking in God knows how much legacy code) `scanf` using a plain `%s` conversion specifier, etc., that can overrun their target buffer;
2. Functions such as `strtok` that use static buffers to store state between calls, and as such are non-reentrant;

As far as *implementation* issues, I don't think anybody who needs a good PRNG is happy with the stock `rand` function in most implementations.

Comment: Considering how long ago it is that Donald Knuth wrote about the mindless copying of bad PRNG code, it is really remarkable that it hasn't stopped yet...

Comment: `scanf using a plain %s conversion specifier`. Damn, I've been using that a lot in my code. Guess I'll have to rewrite parts. Any good alternatives?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: Either put a field width in front of the `%s` specifier (such as `%20s` to read into a 21-char buffer, saving room for the terminating 0) or use `fgets`.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem in ISO C90 and C99 is probably `gets` which is susceptible to buffer overflow. In fact, it seems to have been removed from the new C11 standard.

The ISO C function for getting a temporary file, `tmpnam`, is vulnerable to race conditions on multiuser platforms. The POSIX standard defines a function `mkstemp`, which is safer.

Also, many of the string functions such as `strchr` are not type-safe; they take a `const char*` but return a `char*` into the same buffer, so by using them you can implicitly cast `const` away. Avoiding that is a matter of careful programming, though; the string functions are not inherently unsafe in the way that `gets` and `tmpnam` are.

Finally, many functions such as `strcpy`, `strcat` and `sprintf` do no bounds checking, but since they don't deal with external input like `gets` does, they *can* be used in a safe manner. `snprintf` is the safer alternative to `sprintf` since C99.

Comment: The point is that the language is more than just the code. The language demands that you assign the result of a const-sourced `strchr` to a `const char *`; the language just lacks the expressiveness to enforce that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: you're right, but I still think the string functions deserve listing. Added a note on careful programming.

Comment: @KerrekSB: storing the address of immutable objects in non-`const`-qualified pointer variables is perfectly fine as long as you don't try to modify the object; same thing happens with effective types: in a way, C actually *is* strongly typed - it's just that the type system is unsound, and type constraints only come into effect on evaluation by resulting in undefined behaviour in case of violation...

Answer (score 1):

Some of what you're looking for can be found in the [rationale for TR-24731-1 "Extensions to the C Library Part I: Bounds-checking interfaces"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1173.pdf).

Whether or not you agree with how TR24731-1 tries to address these problems, I think it's a pretty good outline of many of the problems in the C standard library.